# Catch the excepcion in Ocaml

Tags: exception, try-catch, ocaml

I have 2 problems.

First problem:

I do

```
let num1 = int_of_string (get_2 car1) in
```

Where car1 is a pair (string,string)

but int_of_string Raise Failure "int_of_string" if the given string is not a valid representation of an integer.

I whant to do something like:

```
try {
    let num1 = int_of_string (get_2 car1) in
}
catch Failure "int_of_string" {
    let num1 = 0;
}
```

Second problem:

In another function i do:

```
let aa = List.map(fun x -> int_of_string x) right in
```

where right is a list os string, mostly they are numbers, but some of its elements can be strings like: "SID", "SMAX" and these break the function, releasing me:

```
Fatal error: exception Failure("int_of_string")
```

**I CAN NOT USE RECURSION AND PATTERN MATCHING, i have to do with List function.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml exceptions are handled via the `try` ... `with` ... statement. This is similar to the `try` statement in C++ or Java, except that the `with` part follows OCaml's pattern matching syntax.

First of all, let's write a function that converts a string to an int, returning a default value when an exception is raised. The exception `Failure` that `int_of_string` can raise is declared as:

```
exception Failure of string
```

So, we need to match on `Failure str` for the appropriate string `str`:

```
let int_of_string_default str default =
  try
    int_of_string str
  with Failure "int_of_string" -> default
```

Note that you will get a warning when compiling this. This is because the `"int_of_string"` part of the pattern may change in future versions of the language. We can elide this, though, since there's only one way that `Failure` can be raised in this context:

```
let int_of_string_default str default =
  try
    int_of_string str
  with Failure _ -> default
```

We can now write `num1` easily as:

```
let num1 = int_of_string_default (get2 car1) 0
```

and your list function as:

```
let aa = List.map(fun x -> int_of_string_default x 0) right
```

Comment: Note: by reversing the order of arguments to your fucntion, you might write `let aa = List.map (int_of_string_default 0) right`

Answer (score 0):

I think that found the solutions:

First problem:

```
let num1 = try int_of_string (get_2 car1) with int_of_string -> 0 in
```

Second problem:

```
let aa = List.map(fun x -> try int_of_string x with int_of_string->0) right in
```

Comment: This is not quite what you want: what you're doing here is catching an arbitrary exception and naming it `int_of_string`. I'll outline how it works in a different answer.